# Typescript ES6 module syntax with ambient d.ts module

Tags: typescript, tsc

So lets imagine I have a 50 file module, and each one contains:

`export class <SomeClassName> { /* content */ }`

Then, I create a root file to simplify usage by re-exporting all the files. So it would look like:

```
export * from "./src/some-class-1";
export * from "./src/some-class-2";
export * from "./src/some-class-3";
// etc
```

Then, I run it through TSC to do a "common" module targeting "es5" with descriptor output.

So far so good. I have my `package.json` with name `my-module` target the outputted `index.js` as the entry point for my module. So I now go and decide to consume this module in another typescript project.

So I do the npm install for it (lets pretend) `npm install my-module` and it all pulls in, so I now have the d.ts files which were generated, and I have the actual commonjs module so I can use it all. Everything seems to be fine.

Then comes the problem. I then decide to make use of the module:

`import {SomeClass1} from 'my-module'`

It blows up as in the TS world, it doesn't know what `my-module` relates to, as if we go back and look at the index.js which was outputted, it does not contain an ambient module.

So here is the problem, common modules generally use the package.json as the point of reference when including module names, however TS uses the d.ts files. So then I thought well ok, I need to wrap my re-exports in `index.ts` in a module, so I try:

`export module "my-module" { /* all other re-exports */ }`

But turns out you can only use string module names for ambient modules, and you can only put them within d.ts files, however my d.ts file is generated from the existing codebase.

So here is my dilemma, I can manually go in and add a `declare module "my-module` wrapper to my d.ts, but it's not very automated, or I do like the blog posts with ES6 syntax do and reference the file relatively which would end up with lots of `import {blah} from "../node_modules/my-module/dist/index"`, which hopefully we can all agree is a bit silly.

So I cannot find any sort of other approach which would work in the automated world, as all blog posts and docs on this subject when you use the ES6 syntax all use relative file imports, not imports from when the whole thing has been compiled and shared via d.ts files.

So is there a way here to wrap my re-exports in a textual module name? Or at least tell the index.d.ts to be contained with an ambient module? (as remember it will output a d.ts file for every file in the project, but we only care about importing the module via the index.d.ts as that re-exports everything).

Comment: You can create a separated `d.ts` file that references the generated one and declare your ambient module in there. Hopefully this won't be necessary anymore when people move to `System.js`

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a hack as I would need to manually write that file and then hide it somewhere and put it in after build has finished. If there is no other solution I guess I can look into this, but hopefully there is a more elegant solution as it doesnt seem to be a CRAZY use case here. Also I currently I do build for system module type as well but there seems to be some issues around that, and I think its going to be a while before nodejs is easy enough to use with es6 modules without lots of runtime babel stuff.

Comment: I have just tried this now as it seems to fail `error TS2439: Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally have it working, well for CommonJS at least.

Now with typescript 1.6 changes the TS module resolution will check `node_modules` folder for an `index.d.ts` file. So I have basically added this file at the end of the build process which points to my `dist/definitions/index.d.ts` file which includes all the exports.

This way you can do an import like `import * from "my-module"` and as long as in your `node_modules` folder you have a `my-module` folder with an `index.d.ts` it will basically treat everything within that index as a module.

I will happily change the answer to another one if anyone else gets a better solution which works for all and not just commonjs but for the moment it is enough to get me going and hopefully it may help someone else.

Comment: Although there are still some issues when generating d.ts files on projects which depend upon this sort of inclusion system.

Comment: I'm currently trying to get something similar working in an AMD project, however I'm struggling. I'm building a library called `A`, and I've actually manually copied the d.ts files generated by project into `node_modules/A/` and renamed main module d.ts file to `index.d.ts` but I'm still getting compiler errors saying 'Cannot find module A'.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you still need to use another tool to generate a single .d.ts file for your package. There are a few tools that can do that:

- [dts-generator](https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator)
- [dts-bundle](https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle)
- [autodts](https://github.com/charto/autodts) - aims to make it easier to consume the generated .d.ts in packages published to NPM

Personally I'm using a [customized version of dts-generator](https://github.com/enlight/dts-generator) that makes use of tsconfig.json and works with nightly TypeScript builds. You can see a .d.ts that it generated for one of my packages [over here](https://github.com/enlight/polymer-ts-decorators/blob/master/lib/decorators.d.ts).

Comment: The bundle looks like it may be the solution here, will try it shortly and give you the answer if it works as expected.

Comment: There currently seems to be a bug with `dts-bundle` (raised on the issues) which stops it compiling when you have non relative modules (i.e npm style module includes). The other `dts-generator` doesn't seem to support ES6 syntax so that cannot be used in the context of this problem.

Comment: Try out the ts-next branch in my fork of dts-generator (link is in the original answer), it uses ES6 syntax and nightly builds of TypeScript (if you want to use the latest stable TypeScript release instead just modify package.json).

Comment: Do I need to provide individual files or can I just include the baseDir? as if I do that it seems to not find any of the typings, so can I use the baseDir as the folder of all my d.ts files and somehow provide the typings? (I noticed the externals for the reference syntax but thats not very ES6)

Comment: I reference all the `.ts` and `.d.ts` files in the `tsconfig.json`, set the `baseDir` option to the directory containing `tsconfig.json`, and set the `excludes` option to match the `.d.ts` files I don't want inlined into the generated `d.ts` (even though they're not inlined they're still part of the compilation context so type resolution works as you'd expect)... [example](https://github.com/debugworkbench/core-components). Since I don't inline the `.d.ts` files into the generated `.d.ts` I have to explicitly include all the relevant typings in any project that consumes the generated `.d.ts`.

Comment: I dont use a tsconfig file, as I output to many module types. I guess I can add one purely for the d.ts creation.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile `index.ts`, you need to tell TSC to generate the definition file for you.

index.ts:

```
export * from "./src/some-class-1";
export * from "./src/some-class-2";
export * from "./src/some-class-3";
```

command:

```
tsc --declaration index.ts
```

This should generate a `d.ts` file for index with the export in it along with a `d.ts` for each of `some-class-*` with their exports.

Of course, the user will need to reference all of the `d.ts` files in order for this to work which is a PITA at the moment; see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927). I believe you can use the `--out` option to combine all of the files into one, which includes the `d.ts`. Though, I'm not sure that is what you want either.

Comment: out will only work if you are not using module outputs to my knowledge, also currently I do the above command (via gulp typescript) for all files, the fundamental problem is none of the files output will contain a module declaration. So the index.d.ts is output correctly and has all the exports, just if I were to try and import them `import * from "my-module"` how does it know what `my-module` is? as none of the declaration files will contain it.